# Does it matter where you place the curly-braces} when using relational operators in an if statement?

Tags: c++, syntax, curly-braces

```
if (7>4) {
cout << "Yes";}
```

Is there a syntax rule on where to exactly to place the curly braces?

Comment: no, and you can just ignore the curly braces in this case

Comment: Welcome to SO! Folks here are excited and eager to help you with your question but it's important to help them help you. Consider using [backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for code sections, it increases readability. For example `41 + 1 = 42` is easier to read than 41 + 1 = 42. Again welcome and good skills moving forward :)

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not meaningful for C++. If there is a single statement, you can omit them as well.